# jquery code fancybox showing an error 2nd time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have thie following and its works fine, the very first, but next time, if i try to open, i get an error

```
/* select 2 */
    $("#otherlogins").niceSelect();

    $(document).on("change",".socialselection",function() {
        var e = $(this);
        var mode = $('div.nice-select.socialselection span.current').text();
        if(e.val() == '') {
            jAlert('warning', 'Please Choose the Service which you want to use for Login', 'Oops');
        } else {
            $('<link/>', {rel: 'stylesheet',type: 'text/css',href: '/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css'}).appendTo('head'); 
            var script_arr = [
                'jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js', 
                'jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js', 
                'jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js'
            ];
            $.getMultiScripts(script_arr, '/js/fancybox/').done(function() {
                $.fancybox({
                    'width'         : '75%',
                    'height'        : '75%',
                    'autoScale'     : false,
                    'transitionIn'  : 'none',
                    'transitionOut' : 'none',
                    'type'          : 'iframe',
                    'href'          : 'openlogin.cfm?mode='+ mode
                });
            });
        }   
    });
```

The Problem seems where i might be loading the fancybox when its needed, but i am bit lost as to why it is behaving this way

**multiselect function**

```
$.getMultiScripts = function(arr, path) {
        var _arr = $.map(arr, function(scr) {
            return $.getScript( (path||"") + scr );
        });

        _arr.push($.Deferred(function( deferred ){
            $( deferred.resolve );
        }));

        return $.when.apply($, _arr);
    }
```

error i get is this when i select it 2nd time,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined
    at N (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:18:284)
    at I (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:19:43)
    at Function.b.fancybox (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:38:325)
    at Array.<anonymous> (js.cfm:622)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
N @ VM362:18
I @ VM362:19
b.fancybox @ VM362:38
(anonymous) @ js.cfm:622
j @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
j @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
x @ jquery.min.js:4
b @ jquery.min.js:4
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
$.ajax @ VM146:1
m.<computed> @ jquery.min.js:4
getScript @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ rfactor.cfm:105
map @ jquery.min.js:2
$.getMultiScripts @ js.cfm:104
(anonymous) @ js.cfm:621
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
trigger @ jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:3
each @ jquery.min.js:2
each @ jquery.min.js:2
trigger @ jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ jquery.nice-select.min.js:4
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

not sure where problem is happening,

what could be wrong, i am not sure

Answer (score 0):

Look, js is asynchronous, I even not sure when you define a variable with `var` inside an event, that will be a uniqe variable (so after the next event, there will be more than one from each in the dom), and this sometime ransom things like this ... try this:

```
$(document).on("change",".socialselection",function()
{
    //let e = $(this); //you dont need this variable in this case
    let mode = $('div.nice-select.socialselection span.current').text();
    if(!$(this).val().length) //<-- I think this solution better for you but:*1
    {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
        let script_arr = //...
```

//...
*1: `if(!$(this).val().length)` will catch when the `val()` is `null` or `''` or `undefined` or `0` (js not some type safe lang, which makes testing difficult), **BUT** **never use in this form:** `if(!$(this).val().length > 0)` because throws a similar error like in your answer, when the value null or undefined *(I guess... I not some js expert, really dont care this lang, just try help)*...

```
$.getMultiScripts = function(arr, path) {
    let _arr = $.map(arr, function(scr) {
        return $.getScript( (path||"") + scr );
    });

    _arr.push($.Deferred(function( deferred ){
        $( deferred.resolve );
    }));

    return $.when.apply($, _arr);
}
```